# Разобрать данные из $_POST на массив

Tags: массивы, post, php

Всем привет!

Вот допустим у меня есть такие данные:

```
$_POST['name'] == 'Vasya';
$_POST['nick'] == 'vasyok003';
$_POST['email'] == 'vasya@gmail.com';
```

Можно ли из ланных выше получить массив ключ-значение:

```
$a = array(
  'name' => 'Vasya',
  'nick' => 'vasyok003',
  'email' => 'vasya@gmail.com'
);
```

При этом я не знаю имена полей. Т.е. их может быть сколько угодно и каких угодно.

Comment: А чем в таком случае ваш массив $a отличается от массива $_POST?

Comment: @klopp после того, как задал вопрос, подумал.. Ведь это действительно одно и тоже))

Answer (score 4):

Обычный foreach.

```
$a = array();
if (isset($_POST)){
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
        $a[$key]=$value;
    }
}
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$a = $_POST;
```

это без проверок :)